# Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Tags: json.net, jira

I'm attempting to build off of Mike Jansen's [JIRA REST Client](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/20204/jira-rest-client-for-net-collaboration), and I'm trying to pull in JIRA version information. I'm new to JSON, so I'm not sure if it's just a formatting issue or what.

When debugging, I have the following token:

```
{[
  {
    "self": "https://<company>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version/10101",
    "id": "10101",
    "name": "2012.3",
    "archived": false,
    "released": false,
    "releaseDate": "2012-10-08"
  },
  {
    "self": "https://<company>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version/10200",
    "id": "10200",
    "name": "2012.4",
    "archived": false,
    "released": false
  }
]}
```

and the following line of code

```
token.Children().Values<T>()
```

is throwing the following error

```
Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken
```

while trying to convert the two version tokens into the corresponding JiraVersion class:

```
using System;
namespace JiraRestClient
{
    public class JiraVersion : JiraObjectBase, IJiraVersion
    {
        public JiraVersion(IJiraRestResponse jiraResponse) : base(jiraResponse) { }
        public string Id { get { return Get<string>("Id", "id"); } }
        public string Name { get { return Get<string>("Name", "name"); } }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those of you familiar with JSON may have noticed quickly that it was, in fact, a problem with the formatting (the extra curly brackets enclosing the array). Like I said, I'm new to JSON, but the end result of my research is that the JsonWrapper.TryGetPath(...) method attempts to traverse the JObject tree and does not produce correctly formatted JSON when what's being retrieved is an array.

My solution was to simplify things by removing JSON.Net from the solution and depending only on RestSharp (just because it makes it so easy to make requests) and the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response.Content) approach.

Comment: Just for the record: you get this exact error with valid JSON too if you try to access what is actually an object like it were an array.